# How to create grouped and stacked bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I have a very huge dataset with a lot of subsidiaries serving three customer groups in various countries, something like this (in reality there are much more subsidiaries and dates):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'subsidiary': ['EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','EU','US','US','US','US','US','US','US','US','US'],'date': ['2019-03','2019-04', '2019-05','2019-03','2019-04', '2019-05','2019-03','2019-04', '2019-05','2019-03','2019-04', '2019-05','2019-03','2019-04', '2019-05','2019-03','2019-04', '2019-05'],'business': ['RETAIL','RETAIL','RETAIL','CORP','CORP','CORP','PUBLIC','PUBLIC','PUBLIC','RETAIL','RETAIL','RETAIL','CORP','CORP','CORP','PUBLIC','PUBLIC','PUBLIC'],'value': [500.36,600.45,700.55,750.66,950.89,1300.13,100.05,120.00,150.01,800.79,900.55,1000,3500.79,5000.36,4500.25,50.17,75.25,90.33]})
print(df)
```

I'd like to make an analysis per subsidiary by producing a stacked bar chart. To do this, I started by defining the x-axis to be the unique months and by defining a subset per business type in a country like this:

```
x=df['date'].drop_duplicates() 
EUCORP = df[(df['subsidiary']=='EU') & (df['business']=='CORP')] 
EURETAIL = df[(df['subsidiary']=='EU') & (df['business']=='RETAIL')] 
EUPUBLIC = df[(df['subsidiary']=='EU') & (df['business']=='PUBLIC')]
```

I can then make a bar chart per business type:

```
plotEUCORP = plt.bar(x=x, height=EUCORP['value'], width=.35)
plotEURETAIL = plt.bar(x=x, height=EURETAIL['value'], width=.35)
plotEUPUBLIC = plt.bar(x=x, height=EUPUBLIC['value'], width=.35)
```

However, if I try to stack all three together in one chart, I keep failing:

```
plotEURETAIL = plt.bar(x=x, height=EURETAIL['value'], width=.35)
plotEUCORP = plt.bar(x=x, height=EUCORP['value'], width=.35, bottom=EURETAIL)
plotEUPUBLIC = plt.bar(x=x, height=EUPUBLIC['value'], width=.35, bottom=EURETAIL+EUCORP)
plt.show()
```

I always receive the below error message:

---

ValueError: Missing category information for StrCategoryConverter; this might be caused by unintendedly mixing categorical and numeric data

ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units:   subsidiary     date business   value
0         EU  2019-03   RETAIL  500.36
1         EU  2019-04   RETAIL  600.45
2         EU  2019-05   RETAIL  700.55

---

I tried converting the months into the dateformat and/or indexing it, but it actually confused me further...

I would really appreciate any help/support on any of the following, as I a already spend a lot of hours to try to figure this out (I am still a python noob, sry):

1. How can I fix the error to create a stacked bar chart?
2. Assuming, the error can be fixed, is this the most efficient way to create the bar chart (e.g. do I really need to create three sub-dfs per subsidiary, or is there a more elegant way?)
3. Would it be possible to code an iteration, that produces a stacked bar chart by country, so that I don't need to create one per subsidiary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As an FYI, stacked bars are not the best option, because they can make it difficult to compare bar values and can easily be misinterpreted. The purpose of a visualization is to present data in an easily understood format; make sure the message is clear. Side-by-side bars are often a better option.
- Side-by-side stacked bars are a difficult manual process to construct, it's better to use a figure-level method like [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html), which will create a single, easy to read, data visualization.
- Bar plot ticks are located by 0 indexed range (not datetimes), the dates are just labels, so it is not necessary to convert them to a `datetime dtype`.
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### `seaborn`

```py
import seaborn as sns

sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=df, col='subsidiary', x='date', y='value', hue='business')
```

[image]

### Create grouped and stacked bars

- See [Stacked Bar Chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html) and [Grouped bar chart with labels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html)
- **The issue with the creation of the stacked bars in the OP is `bottom` is being set on the entire dataframe for that group, instead of only the values that make up the bar height.**
- **do I really need to create three sub-dfs per subsidiary**. Yes, a `DataFrame` is needed for every group, so 6, in this case.

  - Creating the data subsets can be automated using a `dict-comprehension` to unpack the `.groupby` object into a `dict`.

    - `data = {''.join(k): v for k, v in df.groupby(['subsidiary', 'business'])}` to create a `dict` of `DataFrames`
    - Access the values like: `data['EUCORP'].value`
- Automating the plot creation is more arduous, as can be seen `x` depends on how many groups of bars for each tick, and `bottom` depends on the values for each subsequent plot.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels=df['date'].drop_duplicates()  # set the dates as labels
x0 = np.arange(len(labels))  # create an array of values for the ticks that can perform arithmetic with width (w)

# create the data groups with a dict comprehension and groupby
data = {''.join(k): v for k, v in df.groupby(['subsidiary', 'business'])}

# build the plots
subs = df.subsidiary.unique()
stacks = len(subs)  # how many stacks in each group for a tick location
business = df.business.unique()

# set the width
w = 0.35

# this needs to be adjusted based on the number of stacks; each location needs to be split into the proper number of locations
x1 = [x0 - w/stacks, x0 + w/stacks]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for x, sub in zip(x1, subs):
    bottom = 0
    for bus in business:
        height = data[f'{sub}{bus}'].value.to_numpy()
        ax.bar(x=x, height=height, width=w, bottom=bottom)
        bottom += height
        
ax.set_xticks(x0)
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

- As you can see, small values are difficult to discern, and using `ax.set_yscale('log')` does not work as expected with stacked bars (e.g. it does not make small values more readable).

[image]

### Create only stacked bars

- As mentioned by [@r-beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13107804/r-beginners), use [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), or [`.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), to reshape the dataframe to a wide form to create stacked bars where the x-axis is a tuple (`'date'`, `'subsidiary'`).

  - Use `.pivot` if there are no repeat values for each category
  - Use `.pivot_table`, if there are repeat values that must be combined with `aggfunc` (e.g. `'sum'`, `'mean'`, etc.)

```py
# reshape the dataframe
dfp = df.pivot(index=['date', 'subsidiary'], columns=['business'], values='value')

# plot stacked bars
dfp.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0, figsize=(10, 4))
```

[image]